# How to add ARM properly to the build target (Code::blocks)

Tags: debian, software-development, arm, c++

I want to develop C++ applications for my PI on my PC, I made a develop environment in Ubuntu with the Code::blocks IDE. The problem is that my PC is X86, and the PI is ARM. So how can I add ARM to the build target in Code::Blocks? I switched to a ARM compiler, but he can't find the compiler.

```
Could not auto-detect installation path of "GNU ARM GCC Compiler"...
Do you want to use this compiler's default installation directory
```

And:

```
XXX uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! Skipping...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to set up a complete toolchain to do cross-compiling (which includes a linker and libraries). According to [this blogpost](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/) you can set up the ARM toolchain with [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/). After doing that, I would write a makefile or CMakeLists.txt for testing. I don't know Code::blocks but perhaps it can set up Projects based on makefiles or CMakeLists.txt-files.

Comment: One you have an arm linux toolchain installed and working, you can create a Code::blocks compiler entry for it, probably by copying the host linux one and changing the executable names and directories, ie, gcc becomes arm-linux-whatever-gcc ld becomes arm-linux-whatever-ld and so on.  Setting up GDB for gui debugging will be a bit more complicated given the need to work through gdbremote and have a mechanism for deploying to the target.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a cross compiler for Rasberry Pi in Ubuntu by following the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162072/installing-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler

Then you need to create a new entry to use this cross compiler in Code::Blocks.

From the `Settings` menu, select `Compiler...`. In the `Global compiler settings` copy an existing compiler. E.g. select `GNU ARM GCC Compiler` under `Selected compiler` then click the Copy button and enter a compiler name.

Configure the Toolchain executables for the cross compiler like the following:

[image: ToolchainExeSettings]